# How To Start Submitting Magento2 Extension on Magento Marketplace

Tags: magento2, magento2marketplace, magentomodule

Hi its been around almost a year working with magento and during this times, i have learned so many new things form this community about magento first of all thanks you for all the support.

Now coming back tot he question, since i have deep interest working with modules so i want to start up with module development and upload it on the magento market place. so i know every process in details as i know that will be certain points that will be missed in magento 2 documents.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/package/package_mktpl.html

so i want someone to explain it to me, who has already worked on this and has an understanding

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Please be sure to complete your Account Information and Marketplace Profile selection and submission. You will not be able to launch on Marketplace until all the required information is complete and verified by review team, even if your submission has been approved.**

> [Please Click Here and Check it](https://developer.magento.com/account/profile)

> *After completed your flow is given below*

[image]

> [**For More Click Here**](https://amasty.com/blog/how-to-submit-extension-to-magento-marketplace/)

***I Hope This Helps You***

Comment: what are the things they actually review about user profile